# How can I get google play application rates with API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-play, google-play-services

how can I get application rates and comments from google play with JavaScript and Google play API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the review of the apps by https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/list